# Find twitter hashtags using jQuery, and apply a link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter

I'd like to start this off by saying I'm hardly a pro at jQuery, and this seems like a non-standard question.

Basically I'm making a blog in wordpress, and incorporated into the loop it shows tweets from my twitter profile. I would like to know how to select the hashtags from these tweets (ex. #foo) and then apply a html link to the hashtag as follows...

```
<a class="hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/#search?q=foo">#foo</a>
```

The link has to also place the value of the hashtag (minus the #) into the #search?q= part of the link.

Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks, 
Charlie Ryan

EDIT:

The hashtag #foo will be part of a h1, with no tags differentiating the one word such as

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet #foo et adipiscing</h1>
```

So basically I need to find all strings begining with # and replace them with the link as seen above.

Comment: Is the hashtag (the `#foo`) the only word within a tag, or is it more like `<span>blah blah this tweet is hilarious #foo LOL BIT.LY!!1</span>`? Please show a reasonably complete "before" HTML snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply matt, the question has been edited to be more detailed :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would craft a regular expression to find those hashtags and replace them with a link, using backreferences to get the matching tag.

```
hashtag_regexp = /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

function linkHashtags(text) {
    return text.replace(
        hashtag_regexp,
        '<a class="hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/#search?q=$1">#$1</a>'
    );
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').each(function() {
        $(this).html(linkHashtags($(this).html()));
    });
});
```

*Edit*: I've moved the relevant code inside a function that accepts a string with hashtags, and returns the same string with the tags replaced by links. It doesn't rely on jQuery that way.

```
$('p').html(linkHashtags($('p').html()));
```

You just pass it an elements html value and replace the value by the result of calling `linkHashtags`. One could probably write a jQuery plugin to make this easier to use.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3jjD6/6/)

That regular expression might need some work, I'm not sure which characters are allowed to be used inside a hashtag, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: @Charlie Ryan What are you doing if JS is disabled? Btw @Reiner Gerecke +1 Good solution for a problem

Comment: If js is disabled, then it just won't render with the links, which is fine.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke just noticed a small problem, which is my fault for not describing accurately, these will appear on the page in a number of instances, and this currently makes all instances into the same tweet as can be seen http://i51.tinypic.com/ih1mw4.jpg... (this page is a WIP )

Comment: @Charlie how are you calling it? Indeed, my example is flawed when applying to more elements. I've adjusted my answer to fix the example. Basically it's the same what [Matt Ball](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913555/find-twitter-hashtags-using-jquery-and-apply-a-link/4913629#4913629) does in his answer.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke I was calling it from a script within the head, I have since tried moving this to within the wordpress loop, but that just goes crazy, this has rectified the issue, thanks very much :)

Comment: Used this regex to display the hastags from facebook feed. works fine. Thanks

Comment: But what is $1 here? I want the $1 to be the text after the hashtag.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mess around with complex regexs. When you request a user timeline from the Twitter API with /statuses/user_timeline, you can set a parameter called include_entities to true. See this page of documentation:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

This will add a JSON object to every tweet called an entity. The entity will contain all the details about every hashtag in the tweet all neatly parsed out for you. You will get the text of the hashtag, and its starting and stopping positions in the tweet. You can just substitute a linkified version of the tag back into the text before displaying it.

Comment: came here so say same thing

Answer (score 0):

Why are you want to doing this with jQuery? Use a Wordpress Plugin: [**Twittify!**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twittify/)
This plugin simply turns Twitter `@usernames` and `#hashtags into links to the related place on Twitter.

You always should reduce changes in the DOM to a minimum.

Comment: This only seems to work in practice on the post pages of wordpress. I need this to also work in the loop on the index page. Also for aesthetic reasons I want it to include the "#" in the a aswell instead of it rendering like 

`code`
lorem ipsum dolor #<a href="http://twitter.com/#search?q=foo>foo</a>

Comment: This plugin was just an example. Many Plugins should do the job. For example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-twitter-links/ This works within the posts, pages, or comments.

Comment: That's way mor wordpress-centric than the previous answer; jq's way universal.