# Linkify HashTags and Pass to URL

Tags: php, html, url, variables, linkify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find twitter hashtags using jQuery, and apply a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913555/find-twitter-hashtags-using-jquery-and-apply-a-link)

I'm looking to linkify certain or all elements in a page to "linkify" themselves and pass through to the URL, just like twitter.

e.g:

```
Hello check my #thing
```

Click the above #thing and be taken to a custom URL, e.g

```
mysite.com/tag/thing
```

How could this be done?

Thanks!