# Find Twitter Handle in HTML, and make a link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, hyperlink, handle

I am displaying Tweets on an HTML page, and will get tweets reading:

“Lorem ipsum dolor @username conspecetur.” or
“Really loved @example's show”

How can I search this string for all twitter handles, and make them an achor tag linking to that user's twitter account?

Would be interested in something similar for #hashtags as well.

The HTML for a tweet looks like this
The @usernames I want to convert to anchor tags are in `<span class="tweet">`

```
<div id="realtime_rollover_tweet_text">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/IsabelleOC/statuses/309314847345106945" class="twitter-handle" target="_blank">Isabelle O'Carroll</a>
    <span class="tweet">Forget ruffles and ridiculousness  check my kickass cycle outfit feat @NikeUK, @Sophie_Hulme, Ashish and @Topshop</span>
    <span class="category">bloggers</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you show us the html it may help.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just added it. The important part is in `<span class="tweet">`

Comment: So you have <span class="tweet"> for twitter handles?

Comment: Yes, I do @RahulPatil

Comment: To be more exact @RahulPatil, that's where the actual tweet text goes.

Comment: This should help - you just need to change `#` to `@` in the regex... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913555/find-twitter-hashtags-using-jquery-and-apply-a-link

Comment: you could probably do it with the javascript search() function and a regex, i've been trying to fiddlejs you an exemple but I don't have time to deal with regexs right now... technically it should work though, finding any word starting with the character @ and replacing it by a <a> tag with the substring content inside of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple.. Just use .each iteration and replace the string with desired URL

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cmzqv/1/

Solution : Use Regexp

```
   function(i,html) {
    return html.replace(/(@\w+)/g, '<span class="twitterHandle">$&</span>');
});
```

***Working DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/cmzqv/***

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.twitter').each(function() {
            var handle = $(this).text().slice(1);
        var handleUrl = "<span class='twitter'><a href='https://www.twitter.com/"+handle+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</a></span>";
               $(this).replaceWith(handleUrl); 
    });
});
```